# If IsError inside a While loop giving error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of code that creates a concatenation of two fields in an one spreadsheet(ID sheet). It then searches for the concatenation in spreadsheet (S1), and returns a new ID using MATCH. After that, it searches for the new ID in spreadsheet 2 (S2), and returns a final ID, which is entered into a summary field.

The code is:

```
While MC > MD

    Worksheets("ID sheet").Activate

    MF = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Range("U2:W" & Range("U1")), 2, False)   ' Vlookup for part 1
    MG = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Range("U2:W" & Range("U1")), 3, False)   ' Vlookup for part 2
    MH = MF & MG

    Worksheets("S1").Activate
    MI = WorksheetFunction.Match(MH, Range("HC:HC"), 0)         ' Match concatenation in Range HC
    MK = Range("A" & MI)                                        ' Find deal ID

    Worksheets("S2").Activate

    ML = WorksheetFunction.Match("*" & MK & "*", Range("W:W"), 0)     ' Match deal ID in Range W
    MM = Range("F" & ML)                                        ' Find Register ID

    Worksheets("Summary").Activate
    Range("F2").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(MD - 1, 1) = MM                           

    MD = MD + 1

Wend
```

All the concatenations from the ID sheet are found in S1.

However, not all the IDs from S1 are found in S2. When I run the code initially, it returns an error when the first ID is missing in S2.

I tried to enter the following code into the WHILE loop as the first entry.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

This skips the line, but produces false entries in the summary. What I need is a blank entry in the summary sheet (This gives the last value generated before the error).

I then tried:

```
If Not IsError(MI) Then
    MK = Range("A" & MI)                                        ' Find deal ID

    Worksheets("S2").Activate

    ML = WorksheetFunction.Match(MK, Range("W:W"), 0)     ' Match deal ID in Range W
    MM = Range("F" & ML)                                        ' Find Register ID

Else
    MI = ""

End If
```

Thanks to Eddy for the initial resolution.

When I run this, I get a run time error 1004.

I have also tried this code, with the same results:

```
If IsError(ML) Then
        MF = 0
        MG = 0
        MH = 0
        MI = 0
        MK = 0
        ML = 0
        MD = MD + 1

    Else
        MM = Worksheets("S2").Range("F" & ML)                                        ' Find Register ID

        Worksheets("Summary").Activate
        Range("F2").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(MD - 1, 1) = MM                            ' set value in F4 to the MFGI ID

        MD = MD + 1
    End If
```

**EDIT**

Further to suggestions, I've updated my code to reflect the need to have an IF ISERROR after each match call.

The code now reads as:

```
Dim MF As String
Dim MG As String
Dim MH As String
Dim MI As Variant
Dim MK As String
Dim ML As Variant
Dim MM As String

While MC > MD

    MF = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Worksheets("ID sheet").Range("U2:W" & Worksheets("ID sheet").Range("U1")), 2, False)   
    MG = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Worksheets("ID sheet").Range("U2:W" & Worksheets("ID sheet").Range("U1")), 3, False)   
    MH = MF & MG                                                ' combine 
    MI = Application.Match(MH, Worksheets("S1").Range("HC:HC"), 0)        ' Match combined 

    If Not IsError(MI) Then
        MK = Worksheets("S1").Range("A" & MI)                                        ' Find deal ID
        ML = Application.Match(MK, Worksheets("S2").Range("W:W"), 0)                          ' Match deal ID in Range W

        If Not IsError(ML) Then
            MM = Worksheets("S2").Range("F" & ML)

        Else
            ML = vbNullString
            MM = vbNullString

        End If

    Else
        MI = vbNullString
        MM = vbNullString

    End If

    Worksheets("Summary").Activate
    Range("F2").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(MD - 1, 1) = MM                            ' set value in F4 to the ID

    MD = MD + 1

Wend
```

Fixed the run time error by changing DIM to VARIANT

Comment: Rather than use the worksheet function which will return an error if no matches are found, try using VBA Find: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx.  You can then use something like `IF NOT FoundAddress IS NOTHING THEN do something`

Comment: You have "If .. Else .. End" -> this should be "End If"

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I had a look at the setup for find. While useful, it doesn't real solve the issue, as I need the Row number from MATCH. However, I think I will be using it for later in the code for another problem I have.

Comment: Row number can be returned from the FIND as it returns a reference to the cell - so FoundAddress.Row, FoundAddress.Column or FoundAddress.Address will all return information about the location of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to Match needs to be followed by `If Not IsError() Then`, also: replace all `WorksheetFunction.Match` statements with `Application.Match`

so this:

```
If Not IsError(MI) Then
    MK = Range("A" & MI)                                        ' Find deal ID

    Worksheets("S2").Activate

    ML = WorksheetFunction.Match(MK, Range("W:W"), 0)     ' Match deal ID in Range W
    MM = Range("F" & ML)                                        ' Find Register ID

Else
    MI = ""

End If
```

should be changed to:

```
If Not IsError(MI) Then
    MK = Worksheets("S1").Range("A" & MI)    
    ML = Application.Match(MK, Worksheets("S2").Range("W:W"), 0)

    If Not IsError(ML) Then
        MM = Worksheets("S2").Range("F" & ML)
    Else
        MM = vbNullString
    End If
Else
    MI = vbNullString
End If
```

Comment: I replaced WorksheetFunction.Match with Application.Match, please try it again

Comment: Just wanted to clarify the reason for @paulbica's change; WorksheetFunction throws a runtime error that must be handled with _On Error_, but cannot be caught by _IsError()_. Since you have specified _On Error Resume Next_ this is why you're getting strange results. Application.Match has the same functionality, but can be caught with _IsError()_.

Comment: Thanks @Eddy - I should have given a bit more details about the difference

Comment: Thank you, it is working very well now. Thanks for all the help